# Accessing current item in Collection View with parent command

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have an a MAUI front end that connect to a button successfully from the VM with

```
Command="{Binding BindingContext.ImageCreateCommand, Source={x:Reference PageName}}
```

The full MAUI commands are inside a collection view such as

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding class}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:class">
...
    <Button Text="Add" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding BindingContext.ImageCreateCommand, Source={x:Reference WorkNotification}}" CommandParameter="{Binding id}"></Button>
    <Label TextColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryTextColor}" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding id}" Style="{DynamicResource ContentLabel}"/>
    <Label TextColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryTextColor}" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding txt}" Style="{DynamicResource ContentLabel}"/>
..
```

I want to use the CommandParameter="{Binding id} in the collection view so I can do something with the id but I am not successful when I put it in the button CommandParameter

My View Model is such:

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<class> class { get; } = new();

public viewmodel(string funcLoc)
    {
        ImageCreateCommand = new Command(async () =>
        {
           Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
    };
```

The document says You can set the CommandParameter property to arbitrary data to distinguish between multiple buttons if they are all bound to the same ICommand property in the viewmodel which is done because the CollectionView sees the id and displays it.

How do I use an Item in the collection view as a parameter in this command.

Comment: Need to show more code/xaml. Show the complete declaration of the collectionview. Show the declaration of “class viewmodel”, not just the constructor. Is its ItemSource a collection of “viewmodel”s?  If so, “id” needs to be declared as a property of class “viewmodel”.

Comment: Please provide more details, show more of the relevant code and improve the formatting so that it's easier to read. Also, you shouldn't use reserved keywords, such as `class`, as an identifier for classes and objects in code samples. The code you provide should compile and the presented code won't. It should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to deduce what's wrong from the current state of the question, but I'll provide a generic answer, anyway.

If you have a collection of items and you would like to use them or any of their properties as a *CommandParameter*, then you can do that as follows.

In the ViewModel you have a collection, let's say an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` where `MyItem` is defined as follows:

```cs
public class MyItem
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Your ViewModel, let's call it `MyViewModel` also has a *Command*, let's call that `MyCommand` and it takes a `string` as a parameter, then it will look something like this:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> items;
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items
    {
        get => items;
        set => SetProperty(ref items, value);
    }

    private IRelayCommand<string> myCommand;
    public IRelayCommand<string> MyCommand => myCommand ??= new RelayCommand<string>(MyMethod);

    private void MyMethod(string id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
```

In your XAML, you can then set up a `<CollectionView>` where you can reference the `MyCommand` command and pass in the `Id` property as a parameter.

This requires that you have set an instance of `MyViewModel` as the `BindingContext`, e.g. in the code-behind of your View or Page:

```cs
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

Then, in the XAML of MyPage, you can setup the `<CollectionView>` and *Command* bindings using a [Relative Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) to the ViewModel:

```xml
<CollectionView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyItem">
            <Button
                Text="{Binding Id}"
                Command="{Binding MyCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:MyViewModel}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: usually we can use Commands with direct binding. My Question is when do we need to reference the command and why is not working out of the box?

Comment: is it because binding inside DataTemplate is focused on the MyItem and not on the viewModel?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The `x:DataType` defines the type that will be used for the `BindingContext` of the `DataTemplate`. Without the `x:DataType` this would still be the case, but the binding would then only be resolved during runtime, while in this case it's defined during compile time using [Compiled Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings).